# Deep Learning for Video Classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, computer-vision

Which Deep Learning architecture is best for classifying short videos of variable length? I would like to classify videos that last from 1 up to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use **Convolutional *and* Recurrent** layers in the same Neural Network.

You'd have to capture a given number of frames of a video (let's say one each 0.5 seconds), and feed arrays of screenshots into the model. Its structure would be:

1. Conv (and MaxPool) layers to process pixel data - they will extract and process relevant information from each screenshot.
2. LSTM layers - that will process their sequence, extracting meaning from their flow.
3. Dense layers at the end to perform classification, with softmax activation at the output layer.

That's how I would do. It's going to be computationally expensive, if you don't have a GPU it won't be easy.

Comment: I was thinking something similar to this. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to help, it looks like a really cool Computer Vision project